# Searching strings through for loop and regex

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataset having two columns - **Purpose** and **Employee ID**, Purpose are words / sentences (strings), and Employee IDs are numbers.

[image]

I have list of words which are possible flags that I need to identify in the purpose column against each employee.

I have written the below code

```
flags = ['license','license renewal','anti-virus','facility rental','rent','flowers','project catering','school','education',
'university','academy','membership','book','manual','certification','membership','certified','qualification',
'qualified','body','stationary','electricity','lights','power','supplies','office','desk','chair','Nespresso machine',
'frame','shelves','holiday','medical','medicine','casino','clothing','hair','facial','spa','ATM','cash','liquor','personal'
]

for i in flags:
    wrong_Narration = sample[sample['Purpose']==i]
    print(wrong_Narration)
```

However I got lot of empty dataframe, I realised the column "purpose" are phrases/words and I'm comparing to exact words, so i need to apply regular expression to select a row even if the column has any flagged words along with other words/sentences say for eg. Filter the column having a string "personal" even though the entire sentence would be "personal training"

Hope the above made sense. How do I go about it through a for loop and regular expression? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a part of your original dataframe please?

Comment: `dfg = {'Purpose':['Navratri In Leicester','Personal training','Meeting with XYZ'],'Emp ID':[12345,456789,789123]}
df_table = pd.DataFrame(dfg)
df_table` Hope this would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
wrong_Narration = sample[sample['Purpose'].str.contains(i)]
```

instead of:

```
wrong_Narration = sample[sample['Purpose']==i]
```